# Chef High Availability - Unable to create cluster

Tags: linux, azure, chef-infra, redhat

First Off, thanks for reading. Secondly, I am trying to set up an HA Chef Cluster in Azure. I don't want to use the market place template as they all require paid subscriptions or licenses (BYOL or PAYG).

I am following the documents here: https://docs.chef.io/install_server_ha.html

All Servers/Nodes are Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 fully updated.

Ok, now the question:

Step 3, you need to run:

```
chef-backend-ctl join-cluster <IP_BE1> -s ~/home/<USER>/chef-backend-secrets.json
```

Although, that is wrong, drop the Tilde ~ at the beginning of the secrets path or it will look for /home//home/ and will get you nowhere.

Now, when I run this command on the 2 additional nodes (the master node is already configured), I get the following error:

```
 ✓ Generating configuration
 ✗ Getting peer data from cluster
   Joining node to cluster
   Waiting for the node to come online

An error occurred during this operation:


      Failed to open TCP connection to <IP>:2379 (No route to host - connect(2) for "<IP>" port 2379)
```

Now, all of these servers (1 Cluster Master Node, 2 additional nodes) are in the same Virtual Network, different Subnets but there are no restrictions in the Network Security Group for internal communication. They can ping each other, I an SSH to each other from each other, but nothing when I try to initialize the cluster.

I also checked that Firewall was not running on any of the nodes.

Next, I am going to try and disable SELinux on these boxes and see if that helps. Other than that, anyone else have any ideas?

Requested Netstat Information:

Here it is:

```
netstat -ant|grep 2379
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36228         127.0.0.1:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49575         127.0.0.1:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43861         127.0.0.1:2379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39317         127.0.0.1:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::2379                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          127.0.0.1:49575         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          127.0.0.1:36228         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          127.0.0.1:39317         ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Could you check `netstat -ant|grep 2379` on the master node?

Comment: As chef-backend is a commercial project of Chef Software, you may want to reach out to their support team at support@chef.io

Comment: Netstat info added to post. Thanks for the suggestion, I will see about contacting them. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)